# Adding ChartTitle to Excel works in VBA but not from VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, charts

I'm trying to write a VBScript file (xxx.vbs) that can open a .CSV file, format it and chart the data. Everything works fine except one thing - the setting of the ActiveChart.ChartTitle. When I prototype it in VBA it works fine, but when I do it from the VBScript file, it just seems to ignore it.

Here is a sanitised version of the essentials of my xxx.vbs file:

```
' Using Excel 2013
    Const xlBarClustered = 57, xlLocationAsNewSheet = 1
' Assume for this exercise Excel is already open and on the correct sheet
    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set SheetData = oExcel.ActiveSheet
' Assume Labels in A2:A21, Data in B2:B21 and Title in B1
    oExcel.Range("A2:B21").Select
    SheetData.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    Set aChart = oExcel.ActiveChart
    With aChart
            .Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, "TestChart"
            .ChartType = xlBarClustered
            .SetSourceData oExcel.Range(SheetData.Name & "!A2:B21")
            .HasTitle = True
            With .ChartTitle
' I've tried each of these in turn and none set anything
                    .Text = "=" & SheetData.Name & "!B1"
                    .Formula = SheetData.Name & "!B1"
                    .Caption = "=" & SheetData.Name & "!B1"
            End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a chart without a title in Excel and then ran this code and it worked for me (Excel 2010).

```
Const msoElementChartTitleAboveChart = 2

With GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    .ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementChartTitleAboveChart
    .ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test Title"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. I've been doing my own research and have actually solved my problem. I'll report details a bit later, but thanks for taking the trouble to respond.

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own problem! I began to wonder if the code that 'didn't work' was not attached to the correct object. It turns out that the .Location command changes the ActiveChart object. By reselecting the Chart this now works fine (rest of code as above apart from some additional constants):

```
    SheetData.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    oExcel.ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, "TestChart"
    Set aChart = oExcel.Charts(1)
    With aChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Formula = "=" & SheetData.Name & "!B1"
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MajorUnit = 1
            .MinorUnit = 1
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Caption = "Test"
        End With
        .Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).Crosses = xlMaximum
    End With
```

I hope it might be of some use to someone else!